# Row devuelto desde controller no es reconocido por funcion script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

Estoy armando una tabla con el plugin datatables de jquery, de la siguiente manera:

**Vista**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <input type="hidden" id="idempresa" name="idempresa" value="">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
     hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
      <table id="tablacatalogo" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Slug</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Seleccione</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>
       <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajax_list_examenes($idemp) {
$list = $this->Controlador_model->get_datatables_examenes('examenocupacional');
$lista = $this->Controlador_model->getComparar($idemp);
$data = array();
$no = $_POST['start'];
foreach ($list as $value) {
  $flag = FALSE;
  foreach ($lista as $val) {        
    if ($value->id == $val->examenocupacional){
      $flag = TRUE;
      $campo = "checked";
    }

  }
  $no++;      
  $row = array();
  $row[] = $no;
  $row[] = $value->descripcion;
  $row[] = $value->slug;
  $row[] = $value->precio;
  $row[] = '<td class="center"><div class="pretty p-switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="activar" name="activar" value="'.$value->id.'" '.($flag ? $campo : '').'/>

                  <div class="state p-primary">
                    <label></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </td>';
  //add html for action
  $data[] = $row;
}
$output = array(
  "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
  "recordsTotal" => $this->Controlador_model->count_all('examenocupacional'),
  "recordsFiltered" => $this->Controlador_model->count_filtered('examenocupacional'),
  "data" => $data,
);
//output to json format
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Desde donde imprimo un toggle switch que debería de ejecutarse con esta función, que también está en la vista.

**Script**

```
$('#activar').on('click', function(){
var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
var idemp = $('#idempresa').val();
var exm = $(this).val;
console.log('ingresé al método');
$.ajax({
  url:"<?= $this->url ?>/ajax_update",
  type:'POST',
  data:{mode:mode, idemp: idemp, exm: exm},
  dataType:'JSON',     
  success:function(data)
  {
    var data=eval(data);
    response_result=data.response_result;
    success=data.success;
    $("#heading").html(success);
    $("#body").html(response_result);
  }
});
});
```

Pero no logra ejecutarse, el script al parecer no reconoce al toggle switch devuelto desde mi controlador.

Necesito que al clicar en switch este se ejecute, alguna ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema utilizando el id de la fila, lo que me funciono correctamente fue utilizar una clase y hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

**Controlador**

```
$row[] = '<td class="center"><div class="pretty p-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="activ" id="activar" name="activar" value="'.$value->id.'" '.($flag ? $campo : '').'/>
      <div class="state p-primary">
        <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
</td>';
```

**Actualmente utilizas**

```
$('#activar').on('click', function(){});
```

**Ahora puedes utilizar**

```
$('#tablacatalogo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td .activ', function () {});
```

Así mismo tienes que verificar que la petición de `AJAX` si este regresando bien la información.